# submission of bootstrap form with dynamic form ids

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, modal-dialog

I am listing user's records along with edit link, upon clicking on edit link bootstrap modal form loads

My Page has following code (not sure if there is any better way to create modal dynamically)

after changes when user submits modal form, modal will disappeared and update message will be shown on users.php page

but my alert box shows same form id for every modal's submit button i click (i.e. the first modal's form id) and shows blank datastring (form seriralize)

I want to pass respective form's data to process.php

below is part of my users.php

```
<?php whlie($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
<div id="editkey" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; ">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
      <h3>Edit users Details</h3>
   </div>
<div>
<form id="keyfrm<?=$row['id'];?>">
   <fieldset>
   <input type="hidden" name="keyid" value="<?=$row['id'];?>">
     <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header text-left"><p>Name :</p></li>
        <li class="nav-header text-left"><p><input type="text" name="name"></p></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  <fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">submit</button>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
```

I have js file that contains

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function() {
   var formID = $('form').attr('id');
   alert(formID);
   var datastring = $(this).closest('form').serialize();  // may be working
   alert(datastring);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update_user.php',
    data: datastring ,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
            var data=msg.split('|');
            $(data[0]).modal('hide');
            $('#result').html('');
            $('#result').fadeOut("slow");
            if(data[1]==='Success'){
                $('#result').css('background-color','#DDF9B3');
                $('#result').text("Data is updating...please wait for changes to take effect");
                window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},3000)
            }else{
                $('#result').css('background-color','#FE9898');
                $('#result').text("Error Occured");}
            //$('#result').html(msg);
            $('#result').fadeIn("slow");
            $("#result").delay(4200).fadeOut(800);
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Get the formID same way you get the data:

```
var formID = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
   alert(formID);
   var datastring = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

Comment: i tried this but formID displays undefined and datastring blank

Comment: What I can think of, that you have many button#submit elements, which is a bad pattern, why don't you try `id="submit-<?=$row['id'];?>"'` and set the handler  `$('.btn-success').click(`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G6ehD/, lot unclosed tags in html code, button is outside of from, i hope he fiddle will help

Comment: i am not sure what else i'm doing wrong here, i tried to follow it but still its not working, may be because my jquery knowledge is poor. i have uploaded demo page here http://pastehtml.com/view/dg9fy7dhz.html, you can have a look at it and see what am i doing wrong here, i'm sorry for the trouble

Comment: ohh i got it, i changed modal div id="editkey" with id="editkey<?=$row[0];?>" and in clickable links too, it now shows unique id for each link i click :) but still my main page not working, there must be other jquery or boostrap interfering wiht it, i will have to clean up my code. But i'm glad this test worked and now i know how it is to be done. thank you "cske" for your help